# Enable and validate CORS using nginx

Tags: nginx, cors

I am trying to understand and test CORS feature by enabling it it nginx webserver and proxypass request to backend flask based application. Here are the details.

1. Backend flask App

```
[admin@fedser flask]$ cat postjson.py 
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/postjson', methods=['POST'])
def process_json():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        json = request.json
        return json
    else:
        return 'Content-Type not supported!'
```

Sample JSON data

```
[admin@fedser flask]$ cat postdata.json 
{
"name": {
    "firstname": "Alice",
    "middlename": "Wonder",
    "lastname": "land"
},
"age": 20,
"gender": "Male"
}
```

Launch flask application

```
[admin@fedser flask]$ flask --app postjson run --host=fedser.stack.com --port=2121 &
```

2. Enable CORS on nginx with proxypass and restart service

```
[admin@fedser nginx]$ cat nginx.conf
...
server {
    location /proxyflask {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "fedser.stack.com";
        proxy_pass http://fedser.stack.com:2121/postjson;
    }
    }
...
```

3. Test CORS feature

As per my understanding of CORS feature if a request comes with same origin in my case origin is "fedser.stack.com" it should be allowed as below.

```
[admin@fedser flask]$ curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" 'http://fedser.stack.com/proxyflask' -d @postdata.json -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 192.168.29.117:80...
* Connected to fedser.stack.com (192.168.29.117) port 80 (#0)
> POST /proxyflask HTTP/1.1
> Host: fedser.stack.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.85.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 106
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.22.1
< Date: Wed, 05 Apr 2023 02:58:58 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 96
< Connection: keep-alive
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: fedser.stack.com
< 
{"age":20,"gender":"Male","name":{"firstname":"Alice","lastname":"land","middlename":"Wonder"}}
* Connection #0 to host fedser.stack.com left intact
```

But if i change the Origin to "example.com" by setting the header i am assuming it should block my request as per the cors restrictions that i enabled but it does not happen that way.

```
[admin@fedser flask]$ curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Origin: http://example.com" 'http://fedser.stack.com/proxyflask' -d @postdata.json -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 192.168.29.117:80...
* Connected to fedser.stack.com (192.168.29.117) port 80 (#0)
> POST /proxyflask HTTP/1.1
> Host: fedser.stack.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.85.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/json
> Origin: http://example.com
> Content-Length: 106
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.22.1
< Date: Wed, 05 Apr 2023 02:46:05 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 96
< Connection: keep-alive
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: fedser.stack.com
< 
{"age":20,"gender":"Male","name":{"firstname":"Alice","lastname":"land","middlename":"Wonder"}}
* Connection #0 to host fedser.stack.com left intact
```

Kindly let me know if i am missing something here and on my understanding about cors.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is correct.

According to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS):

> The CORS mechanism supports secure cross-origin requests and data transfers between browsers and servers.

So you can't generate the error in `curl`.